# How could I save data in mongoDB from watson studio using jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, watson-studio

I have a machine learning project in IBM Watson Studio which should save data in a mongoDB (as IBM Service). How can I connect from my notebook in IBM Studio to the mongoDB and save data there using python environnement or Spark & python environnement?

Answer (score 0):

In Cloud Pak For Data / Watson Studio, in your project, you can use new Asset and then choose connection.

And then you will see

[image]